# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'method', Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on an investing project and I get the following error when I try to render the following method from the model:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'method'
```

Here is the code that I wrote, `models.py`:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    # Company data    
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    outstanding_shares = models.IntegerField()
    share_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    revenue = models.IntegerField()
    expenses = models.IntegerField()
    total_assets = models.IntegerField()
    total_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
    current_assets = models.IntegerField()
    current_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
    operating_cashflows = models.IntegerField()
    capex = models.IntegerField()     
    
    # Date of creation
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    # Company methods        
    def net_income(self):        
        return self.revenue - self.expenses

    def net_assets(self):
        return self.total_assets - self.total_liabilities

    def return_on_equity(self):
        return self.net_income / self.net_assets
```

HTML FILE

```
<li>Net income: {{company.net_income}}</li>
<li>Net assets: {{company.net_assets}}</li>
<li>Return on equity: {{company.return_on_equity}}</li>
```

Note that both `net_income` and `net_assets` work just fine. The error rises with the last method, `return_on_equity`.

Comment: You want to divide the results returned by executing the methods: `return self.net_income() / self.net_assets()`

Comment: You can also make those methods into properties by adding `@property` on the line before the `def` and then your code should work as is.